# Host name resolution order - Changes to SYSTEM.INI not reflecting

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, hosts-file

I added the below lines to my system.ini file to ensure that all host name resolution will happen through hosts file only and all other methods are ignored.

```
[DNS]
HostsPriority=1
```

But, the change doesn't seem to work. After making this change, I am trying to access google.com under the assumption that it will not be loaded as I don't have an entry in host file.

What is that I am missing? Is my understanding about host name resolution correct?

Comment: Have you rebooted the system since editing the file?

Comment: Yes. I did restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Microsoft documentation I can find on editing this setting in System.ini says that it applies to **Windows for Workgroups 3.11**.  Fewer and fewer System.ini file settings are actually honored with each successive edition of Windows. If the functionality was still used, it was likely moved to the registry.

If you don't want to use DNS servers, then just remove the DNS server IP addresses from the TCP/IP settings on your network adapter.

Edit: I was able to find these settings such as HostsPriority and LocalPriority in the registry at HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\ServiceProvider. Regardless, I still refer you back to my previous statement that if you don't want to use your DNS servers, then just remove them from the TCP/IP settings on your NIC. If you don't want to use NetBIOS, then just turn it off in your NIC settings.

Comment: Which OS you got it working?